# How to kill MaxTo.exe through AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

On Windows 10, I need to restart a window-manager running as [MaxTo.exe](https://maxto.net/). However, the following mapping does do the job as desired.

```
^!+m::
    WinKill ahk_exe MaxTo.exe
    run C:\Program Files\MaxTo\MaxTo.exe
return
```

Can anyone suggest what I did wrong? Putting another prime (`,`) after the `WinKill` command also does no help.

With `WinKill ahk_exe gvim.exe`, I can happily terminate any GVIM process. However, I can do nothing to this `MaxTo.exe` guy.

Are there known limitation of `WinKill`? The only difference between the two processes is that: I can see an icon for GVIM popping up in the *taskbar region*, yet when MaxTo is running, it only shows an active icon in the *system tray*.

Thank you in advance!

All the best,

-Linfeng

Comment: "However, the following mapping does do the job as desired." That suggests you don't have a problem. Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the `WinKill` command does not work because there is no window associated with the process. Try using the `Process` command instead like this,

```
^!+m::
    process, exist, MaxTo.exe
    pid = %ErrorLevel%
    Process, Close, %pid%
    run "C:\Program Files\MaxTo\MaxTo.exe"
return
```

Comment: Fantastic. Your script worked like a breeze. Now, effectively, I can *restart* MaxTo.exe with one key-stroke. Thanks a lot!